# how to use regex in php to get something after double back slash

Tags: php, regex

I have this sentence

```
C:\\wamp\\www\\callCenter\\joomlatools-files\\docman-files\\test.pdf
```

And I want to get as a result of my regex exression test but without using another word from the sentence.

My regex is `~\\\(.+)\.pdf~` but I have `wamp\www\portail-callcenter\joomlatools-files\docman-files\test` as a result. 
Can someone please explain how to get it done?

Comment: What are you trying to get from your first sentence exactly?

Comment: `explode("\\", $s)` and get the last item to remove `.pdf` with either `substr` or another explode.

Comment: @Shafizadeh just the word test

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If it's possible i want to do it using regex

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [Wrong](https://regex101.com/r/hB4fO6/3)

Comment: @Shafizadeh: I just confused the slashes (I was checking [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)), the `'~([^\\\\]+)\.pdf$~'` regex is correct

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that does'n work in my preg_match function

Comment: @Habchi: It does: https://ideone.com/PS61YE

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew got this as error : Warning: preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 13

Comment: Nice try @WiktorStribiżew, but you edited your comment. Your second regexp had only two backslashes in the char class, not four.

Comment: Because it was a regex, not a PHP single quoted literal, I just turned it into a piece of code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Technically you are correct, but OP was expecting string literals and not a naked regexp. His fault for not making the explicit request, I suppose.

Comment: Also, it is not correct to use 3 backslashes to match a literal ``\``, you must use 4 (in both single and double quoted literals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you trying to get. But I guess you want to get the word of `test` from your first sentence. So use this pattern:

```
~\\\\(\w+)\.pdf$~
```

And then `$1` containing what you need.

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hB4fO6/5)

- `~` delimiter
- `\\\\` matches two backslashes literally
- `(` capturing group `$1` *(which is containing what you need to get)*
- `\w+` matches one or more letter, number or underscore
- `\.` matches a dot literally
- `$` end of string

---

Here is your pattern in the question `~\\\(.+)\.pdf~`. The problem of your pattern is `.+`. Because it means *one or more character(s) (every character even `\`)*. So your pattern matches that two backslashes which are in the beginning of your string, and the rest of backslashes will be match as *every character* (`.+`).

To avoid this, you have to use `\w` which means *any letter, number or underscore* instead. In this case the matched part will be just `test`.

Comment: That works like a charm can you exlain it to me please? 'cause using it is good but understanding how it works is even better.

Comment: It matches any word that has two backslashes as a left bound and a dot followed by letters as a right bound.

Comment: @klaar What you said is a part of OP's string structure. What exactly we have to follow and write a pattern based on.

Comment: You are talking about $1 but I don't see it in your regex

Comment: @Habchi Yes it isn't. `$1` is available just into demo. You are using PHP and then `preg_match_all()` function gives you an array of capturing groups. So forget `$1` `;-)` ..! See *SUBSTITUTION* in [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/hB4fO6/6).

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is almost correct. Only thing is it matches every type of character in your *final word*. Change it to

```
~\\\\([^\\]+)\.pdf~
```

This matches everything but a `\` in the final word - and you should get the file name only.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

To get `test` from `C:\\wamp\\www\\callCenter\\joomlatools-files\\docman-files\\test.pdf`:

```
(?<=\\\\)[^.\\]+(?=\.[^.\\]+$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oA3aI9/4)

You can avoid lookarounds by using a group to get the desired portion:

```
\\\\([^.\\]+)\.[^.\\]+$
```

Comment: Nice use of look-ahead and look-behind assertions, but you can avoid using them by grouping the wanted piece of text with braces.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$subject = 'C:\\\\wamp\\\\www\\\\callCenter\\\\joomlatools-files\\\\docman-files\\\\test.pdf';

echo $subject; // C:\\wamp\\www\\callCenter\\joomlatools-files\\docman-files\\test.pdf

preg_match_all('~\\\\\\\\([^\\\\]+)\.pdf$~', $subject, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

result

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '\\test.pdf' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'test' (length=4)
```

If you want to match a double backslash, you need 8 backslashes in your regex. In the first level the string input in the script line is parsed and backslashes are considered as meta chararacters to escape the following character. As result 4 slashes remain in your regex. When executing the regex, the backslashes are treated as well as meta characters, so 2 slashes remain to be compared with the subject string.

```
echo '~\\\\\\\\([^\\\\]+)\.pdf$~';  // ~\\\\([^\\]+)\.pdf$~
```